# Is it possible to install Android apps on mobile running Cyanogen OS?

Tags: applications, installation, cyanogen-os

I have a doubt on Cyanogen OS.

Can I install Android apps (e.g. from Play Store) on mobile (e.g. Lenovo Zuk Z1) running Cyanogen OS?

Answer (score 4):

[Cyanogen OS](https://cyngn.com/about) (not to be confused with [open source CyanogenMod](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/About); is built on Android) comes with Google Mobile Services (GMS) and for GMS to be shipped in a specific device the device must follow Compatibility Definition Document (CDD) as well as pass the compatibility test. Any device which follows the said document and passes the test can be claimed as Android compatible. To know what having an Android compatible device means, refer to the document [Compatibility Program Overview](https://source.android.com/compatibility/overview.html).

So yes, you can install (non-device specific) apps from Google Play Store on your Cyanogen OS.

Comment: Confirmed (Wileyfox Swift here running CyanogenOS 12.1 – ships with all the Google crap included: Playstore, Maps, Chrome, youNameIt). Unfortunately :) But the good thing with CyanogenOS is 1) most bloatware can be easily uninstalled, 2) as CyanogenOS is based on CyanogenMod, switching to the latter usually is easy :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, its absolutely possible:

*CyanogenOS* is a custom version of the Android operating system. It's here to offer a 'better' version than Google can provide, with more features and more control for the hardcore user. You will be having greater access to resources on mobile hardware as compared to normal android users.

For more info visit [their official Website](https://cyngn.com/cyanogen-os) .

Comment: This is an incorrect answer. Why has it gotten an upvote I don't understand? For instance, the author doesn't know that Cyanogen OS doesn't offer root access at all and the question is about Cyanogen OS, not CyanogenMod.

Comment: @Firelord Though I agree, I tend to interpret it as a mis-spelling ("Freudian slip"). Why? Because hitesh gave the correct link (`cygn.com` is the CyanogenOS domain – CyanogenMod would be `cyanogenmod.org`). // But you're absolutely correct that the "root part" of the answer is definitely wrong. I own a device running CyanogenOS, and I had to root it myself (easy though, just flashing the `supersu.zip` :)